# Using TOR and VPN at the same time

Tags: vpn, proxy, privacy, tor, proxy-server

I was wondering if there's a way to use TOR and VPN at the same time, what I want to do is connect to my Wifi then send the encrypted traffic to TOR using the same encryption the VPN uses, then from TOR send it to the VPN which decrypts and acts as exit node for the traffic.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use ToR through a VPN but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

you can use it

```
VPN --- TOR 
VPN ---TOR ---- VPN
```

See [AirVPN's website](https://airvpn.org/tor/) for more information on how to do this.

and also

```
VPN --- TOR --- VPN ---WEB PROXY SSL 
VPN --VM--VPN --- TOR ---VPN---WEB PROXY SSL
```

Answer (score 1):

> what I want to do is connect to my Wifi then send the encrypted traffic to TOR using the same encryption the VPN uses

Tor builds circuits and changes them periodically to defeat traffic analysis.  This means your IP changes every so often.  So you can connect to your VPN provider, but the connection will only last until your IP changes.  This will severely hamper your ability to use the VPN usefully through Tor.  You may also experience issues if your VPN provider blocks IPs coming from certain countries, and some exit nodes may prohibit VPN traffic if it doesn't occur on port 80 or 443.  If your VPN is UDP or GRE based it won't work, as Tor only tunnels TCP traffic.

> then from TOR send it to the VPN which decrypts and acts as exit node for the traffic.

You can't change the exit nodes from the Tor client.

You need to be running the Tor software to act as an exit node.  A VPN in and of itself cannot act as an exit node.